# Get more specific Schema.org markup for my website

Tags: html5, microdata, schema.org

This is current schema [see](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?url=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.lightpostcounseling.com%252Fdemo%252F)

I want to write best specific with Google to promote my website using structured data markup. My business is "Counseling" in "Mental Health" category.

Sample Schema for Product with Category :

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<span itemprop="category" content="Home > Bedding" ></span>
</div>
```

I need like below for my business. Can I do it? I don't know what schema is best for showing my business.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/XXXXXXX">
<span itemprop="category" content="Mental Health > Counseling"></span>
</div>
```

I want to specific my website by schema.org microdata by Category. However, MedicalTherapy and LocalBusiness has not category. Is there any way that is better than explaining in description in LocalBusiness?

Relate : schema : MedicalTherapy / LocalBusiness

Comment: Since I cannot read Thai, it's a bit hard to get whether or not you got it right. But it looks like it is. There are different markup options for schema.org, but I'd always suggest using microdata over microformats. You might find these links helpful: https://builtvisible.com/micro-data-schema-org-guide-generating-rich-snippets/ - and: http://searchengineland.com/schema-markup-structured-data-seo-opportunities-site-type-231077. (BTW: You could probably also use http://getschema.org/index.php/MedicalOrganization instead of LocalBusiness or in addition to LocalBusiness).

Comment: Thank you so much @Ginna. My business is counseling, coaching and training only

Comment: Note that you [can’t use the `content` attribute for `span`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27089168/1591669) in Microdata (only for `meta`).